# Very slow loading Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm refactoring our Access app that currently has an Access backend to now use a SQL Server backend.
All but one form are now loading and working very well but one form, by no means the most complex or the most simple, takes about 1 minute or more to load.

My plan was to create a copy, remove subforms from the copy and check it's load time to determine whether one of the subforms was the delay but with NO changes from the original, the copy loads immediately, provided the original is in place.  If I delete the original, the copy takes 1 minute or more to load.
Does anyone have any thoughts about what might be happening?

Comment: If the copy is using the same subforms as the original then it is likely that one of the subforms is what is causing the delay.  If the subform has already loaded into the original then it might not need to do (whatever it is it does) again.  The way to prove this would be to delete the copy, load the subforms and then open the original main form and see if it now loads instantly.

Comment: Thanks Gareth.  If I understand your suggestion, that was my plan but before removing any of the subforms from the copy and with the original main form closed, I opened the copy and it opened instantly.
It seems to me that there might be some referencing of the original form that can happen more efficiently from a copy than it can if there's only one instance of the original form.  In other words, self-referencing causes thrashing but referencing of a duplicate results in no thrashing.  If this is a valid thought, it seems I might get an "out of stack space" error... but that's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem but without a complete root cause understanding.
While troubleshooting, as noted in my original problem statement, I noticed some unusual behavior that seemed to be associated with the form name.
In the end, I renamed the form, updated the call to it and Shazam!, problem solved.  The form now opens instantly and without any other changes.
For the record, the app consists of 160 forms, 44 code modules and 12 class modules.
Gareth, thank you for your input.
If anyone has any thoughts about what might have been the root cause, I'll very gladly look further but for now I need to move forward with development.